# My answer was deleted, and I updated it. How do I vote to undelete?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28064096/347339) was deleted. I edited it to address the moderator's concerns. But when I click to undelete I get a message saying a moderator has deleted it, and it may not be undeleted. I also can't comment on it to alert the moderator that I updated my answer... Help please?

Comment: Custom flags go to the mods. Not sure if you can custom flag a deleted answer, but if you can't, custom flag another of your posts and clearly explain 'this is for this deleted answer [link], I did [whatever you had to improve], can it be undeleted now? Or let me know what it's still missing if it's still not up to par' or something like that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your answer was deleted by a moderator. You *can't* vote to undelete. Your options are:

1. Raise a custom mod-flag explaining that you have updated your post such that the reason(s) it was deleted no longer apply. It's recommended that you double check that the changes you have made to your post did, in fact, resolve the issues previously indicated as the problem. Be sure to try reading it as if you are someone else looking at the post without any context.
2. If the custom mod-flag you raised in #1 is declined and you disagree with the reasons it was declined, you have the option of making a post here on Meta.
   However, keep in mind that it would be a rare situation for such a Meta post to be received well by the community. Basically, while it's possible the moderator who declined the flag you raised in #1 may have made a mistake, it's relatively rare for that to happen. Prior to posting here on Meta, it's strongly suggested that you triple check that the changes you made to your post truly do resolve the issues that have been identified with your post, and that no other reasons for deletion would apply either.

   Note that it still requires a moderator to agree that the post should be undeleted, as non-moderators can not undelete posts that moderators have deleted. However, posting on Meta provides a way for you to explain more fully how your changes resolve the issues with the post, allows you to get community feedback on if others feel the issues are resolved, and brings it to the attention of multiple moderators as they read Meta.